# Problema con el método equals

Tags: java, string

Tengo que comprobar si un string tiene al menos una mayúscula y minúscula así que he decidido hacerlo del siguiente modo, pero no entiendo porque no me muestra el if, no veo donde me estoy equivocando. Si podéis decirme el problema os lo agradeceré.

```
package Cadenas;
import java.util.*;
public class Cadenas_Ej6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String frase="";
        String aux=frase.toLowerCase();
        System.out.println("Introduce una contraseña, esta tiene que contener -2 Digitos -1 Mayuscula y 1 Minuscula -2 Digitos -1 Simbolo");
        frase=sc.nextLine();

        if(frase.equals(aux)==true) {
            System.out.println("La contraseña debe tener almenos una Mayúscula y una Minúscula");
        }   

    }

}
```

Comment: No estás dando valor a `aux`, porque la inicializas con el `toLowerCase` de `frase`, que está inicializada a vacío. Así que `frase` nunca va a ser igual a `aux`.

Comment: El código no tiene mucho sentido: frase es una cadena vacía, que copias a aux. Luego lees del teclado, guardando el texto en frase y comparas con la cadena vacía

Comment: La solucion que te han dado es el principal problema que tenias ahora. Pero esa comprobacion solo te funcionara para comprobar si hay alguna mayuscula, si hay o no alguna minuscula siempre te dara el mismo resultado. Debes implementar mas comprobaciones para el resto de condiciones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema está en que estás cargando la variable aux antes de cargar tu variable frase y la carga **vacía**, por eso siempre que compara te da **false**.

Simplemente cárgala después de cargar frase para que pueda compararla correctamente.

```
frase=sc.nextLine();
String aux=frase.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Comprendo, tenía que inicializar después de dar valor a la frase porque sino aux era igual a vacío. Gracias!